# NotesTeX/marginote problem with header and consecutive odd/even pages

Tags: margins, marginnote

I'm trying the NotesTeX.sty (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notestex) in an `twosided` `article` document but it gives me two warnings and the output is problematic.
The warnings are

*Package marginnote Warning: Consecutive even pages found. Note, it is not recommended to use consecutive even pages in a double-ended document. The pages of your document should always be a sequence: odd-even-odd-even-... Maybe you've forgotten a \cleardoublepage before changing the page numbering on page 0.*

and

*Package marginnote Warning: Consecutive odd pages found. Note, it is not recommended to use consecutive odd pages in a double-ended document. The pages of your document should always be a sequence: odd-even-odd-even-... Maybe you've forgotten a \cleardoublepage before changing the page numbering on page 1.*

The wrong output essentially is the wrong header on even pages (in these pages header is aligned to the text and to the margin of the page) and wrong margin notes on odd pages (they overlap text). I put some figure that show the problems.
[image: Margin problem]
[image: Header problem]

I think the problems and the warnings are linked, but I don't know how to solve it.
Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{article}
\usepackage{NotesTeX}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\Huge{\textbf{Title}}}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{
affiliation
}
\emailAdd{mail@mail.com}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagestyle{fancynotes}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[0] \mn{THIS IS A MARGIN NOTE} \lipsum[1]\mn{THIS IS ANOTHER MARGIN NOTE} \lipsum[3]\mn{A FINAL MARGIN NOTE} 
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone will help me.

Comment: As always you are more likely to get help if you provide code that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Are you trying to use \count0 anywhere?

Comment: @JohnKormylo it gives me error.

Comment: @daleif sure. do you suggest also to put all the `notestex.sty` file or not?

Comment: EEk!   I didn't say do it!  \count0 is the page counter.

Comment: If the package is available on ctan we don't need it, but we need an example of your failing code.

Comment: @daleif I've added the MWE

Comment: No idea what's going on with that package at all.

Answer (score 1):

The package does something weird with `\maketitle` and then doesn't seem to like the result. Avoid using this.

```
% notestexprob.tex  SE 573316

%\documentclass[twoside, openright]{article} % article doesn't know openright
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{NotesTeX}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{\Huge{\textbf{Title}}}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{
affiliation
}
\emailAdd{mail@mail.com}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle % NotesTeX does something weird with this and doesn't like the result
% make your own titling, for example very simplistically
\pagestyle{empty}
{\Huge\textbf{Title}}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancynotes}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[0] \mn{THIS IS A MARGIN NOTE} \lipsum[1]\mn{THIS IS ANOTHER MARGIN NOTE} \lipsum[3]\mn{A FINAL MARGIN NOTE} 
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need to use the `NotesTeX` package then tell the package author about your problem.

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve the header problem on odd pages

Comment: @mcp My best suggestion is to not use the `NotesTeX` package. If you want stuff in the margin use the relevant package(s).